# How to disable sound when switching Firefox tabs with ⌘1-⌘9

Tags: macos, keyboard, audio, firefox

I use the keyboard shortcut ⌘1-⌘9 to switch to tabs in Firefox. In OS X every time I do this there's a sound, which can become annoying when the volume is turned up.

I looked in about:config for anything matching `sound` but wasn't able to figure it out. Does anyone know how to disable this sound?

Comment: Nice question, I didn't even know that feature. Sadly, I can't give you a solution because I use windows where I can hear no sound while switching tabs by ctrl1-ctrl9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s certainly not a Firefox sound, at least not one that I’ve heard in the past.

- Do you have any Extension? Try disabling them all for the sake of testing.
- Any other application running that could be using the same shortcut? (Safari uses that to access the quick bookmarks where ⌘1 corresponds to the 1st on the left (next to Top Sites) and so on. However, the lack of bookmark, doesn’t produce a sound on my system. I even have “Play User Interface sound effect” checked in Sound Preferences pane.

My bet is that you have something else running and that is causing the “bonk”.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer -- it's the Vimperator addon. I should have checked!

Comment: @Mike glad you found it!